# Django + Django REST csrf on AJAX direfent site requests

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a **web app** with `django` which has a module who uses the `django-rest-framework` to provide an API used by a **mobile app**.

If I login into the **web app**, the `csrf` tokens on the mobile app throws me an `403 - Forbiden` with the following response

```
   {"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

When I logout from the **web app** I can use the **mobile app** again (even without login again, with the first session).

I've got the following about `django-rest-framework-jwt`

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/v1/.*$'
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=120),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

And finally here is `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'gaeblob_storage',
    ################################## WEB APP MODULES
    'myapp.modulos.presentacion',
    'myapp.modulos.principal',
    'myapp.modulos.proyecto',
    'myapp.modulos.estado_1',
    'myapp.modulos.estado_2',
    'myapp.modulos.estado_3',
    'myapp.modulos.comunicacion',
    ################################## API MODULE
    'myapp.modulos.api',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    # API Rest
    'jwt',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_jwt',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)
```

Also here is the login view,

```
def login_view(request):

    status = ""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/principal') #Cambiar cuando este el estado disponible
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None and user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,request.user)
                    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
                else:
                    status = "Usuario y/o Password incorrecto"
        form = LoginForm()
        ctx = {'form':form, 'status': status}
        return render(request,'presentacion/login.html',ctx)

    return render(request,'presentacion/login.html')
```

Comment: You are using the `module` as an app integrated separately?

Comment: Well, the **web app** has a lots of modules, and the api rest has his own. All of them are listed on the `INSTALLED_APPS` on the main `settings.py`

Comment: Could you provide some more details of the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `REST_FRAMEWORK` in your settings file?

Comment: `If you're using SessionAuthentication you'll need to include valid CSRF tokens for any POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE operations.` from [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/). I am guessing, once you login, there is a session created for the user and so the `SessionAuthentication` is triggered. Try: `from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key

request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _get_new_csrf_key()` for logged in scenario.

Comment: I include the `login view` for more detail. As your link mentioned, I'm no longer sure about the authentication type here; it says `"AJAX requests that are made on a different site from the API they are communicating with will typically need to use a non-session-based authentication scheme, such as TokenAuthentication."`. Does that mean that I should remove the `SessionAuthentication` and the `BasicAuthentication` from the `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting?. Becouse in this case the **mobile app** perferms AJAX requests from diferent site (It is a `apache-cordova` app).

Comment: Yes. Because session is something that you would want to be created for keeping the state of the logged in user. You can actually think about token based authentication.

Comment: I just test it and that was it, has I was performing AJAX request from diferent site (**mobile app**), the `django-rest-framework-jwt` should handle the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` with their `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication`. The `SessionAuthentication` and `BasicAuthentication` should not be there. Thank you very much TheMonk ;)

Answer (score 0):

"By default, a ‘403 Forbidden’ response is sent to the user if an incoming request fails the checks performed by CsrfViewMiddleware. This should usually only be seen when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when, due to a programming error, **the CSRF token has not been included with a POST form**." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#rejected-requests

You need to include the `csrf` token in the form data along with the request.

You can grab it from the cookies or from the DOM, if [CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly) = True.

For more info see [Django's AJAX docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to have the `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` first.

If you supply a valid JWT to your API the request should be authenticated, without checking for a valid session containing a CSRF token.